# Expanding C drive on amazon webservice

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am trying to expand the C disk size ( size is 50 GB)   of a windows instance on amazon ec2 .

I create an ami from the running instance  .

Then i created new instance using the new ami . while creating i have chosen 80 GB for the volume size . But when i lunchaned the new instance the C drive size is still 50 GB .

Can someone tell me why the new machine does not show 80 GB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've expanded the size of the underlying block device only. The second step is to expand the filesystem itself, which you can do in Windows' Disk Management tool.

Comment: You are right that is what i have done . Is expanding the size is specific to hyperv or it is by default in windows server ?

Comment: It's universal, and not just for Windows. The same thing has to happen on Linux operating systems, BSD, etc.

Comment: But if you were using your own computer . Say you have no more space . You purchase new HDD . Can you expand the space of your c drive using the new one you purchased  ? Or it is only specifict to virtualization environnement. That was my question actually .

Comment: That's a completely different subject. Read up on RAID.

Comment: But no, it's not specific to virtualized environments. As I said, it's **universal**.